# Parsing iTunes JSON for TV Series including episodes

Tags: php, json, parsing, itunes

I'm working on a personal project to help organise my iTunes library, to do this i'm using the [iTunes search api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

The code i currently have allows me to parse the information for the Series itself automatically, but i'm trying to change it so it will recognise how many episodes there is in a season and parse the information for them as well, without me having to edit the php for 13 episodes for one season, then 27 for the next.

This is the code i am currently using;

```
$response = file_get_contents($itune_url);
$obj = utf8_decode($response);
$results = json_decode($obj);

$artwork = $results->results[0]->artworkUrl100;
$collectionViewUrl = $results->results[0]->collectionViewUrl;
$collectionType = $results->results[0]->collectionType;
$collectionId = $results->results[0]->collectionId;
$collectionName = $results->results[0]->collectionName;
$trackCount = $results->results[0]->trackCount;
$collectionPrice = $results->results[0]->collectionPrice;
$genre = $results->results[0]->primaryGenreName;

$trackNumber1 = $results->results[1]->trackNumber;
$trackName1 = $results->results[1]->trackName;
$shortDescription1 = $results->results[1]->shortDescription;
$longDescription1 = $results->results[1]->longDescription;
```

Is there anyway to set my PHP so it recognises the $trackCount and automatically generates the next set of results? e.g.

```
$trackNumber1 = $results->results[1]->trackNumber;
$trackName1 = $results->results[1]->trackName;
```

Then:

```
$trackNumber2 = $results->results[2]->trackNumber;
$trackName2 = $results->results[2]->trackName;
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `json_decode` expects string to be UTF-8, **not** to be *not* UTF-8. Are you open to arrays?

Comment: @hakre Unfortunately I'm new to both this site and new to php, I'm trying to learn while doing a project that will be of use to me. I'm not sure what you mean by open to arrays? I'm don't think currently using them but if they will help me get the results i want i'm willing to use them, just don't have a clue on how i would use them in this instance? Any ideas on how i could use them here?

Answer (score 0):

You could make good use of `foreach` ([docs](http://php.net/foreach)) to loop over the JSON results, and nested arrays ([docs](http://php.net/arrays)) to hold all of the episode information.  That could cut down your making-sense-of-the-JSON-result phase into something like the following.

```
$url  = 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=firefly&media=tvShow&entity=tvEpisode&attribute=showTerm';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$results = array();
foreach ($data->results as $r) {
    $season  = $r->collectionName;
    $episode = $r->trackNumber;
    $results[$season][$episode] = $r;
}
```

The results array has the following structure.

```
array (
  'Firefly, Season 1' => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'wrapperType' => 'track',
      'kind' => 'tv-episode',
      'artistId' => 151198837,
      'collectionId' => 151801083,
      'trackId' => 151961947,
      'artistName' => 'Firefly',
      'collectionName' => 'Firefly, Season 1',
      'trackName' => 'Serenity',
      ...
    ),
    ...
  ),
)
```

This means that you can access individual episodes by number, like `$results['Firefly, Season 1'][3]` for the episode `Bushwhacked` or you can loop over a season:

```
foreach ($results['Firefly, Season 1'] as $episode) {
    echo $episode['trackName'], PHP_EOL, $episode['longDescription'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Of course, if you don't care about the season  (all your results return a single season of a show?) or want to get multiple shows in the results (what are you searching on?!) then the same process can be employed, just with different criteria and more (or less) depth of the results array structure.

Comment: All my results will return episode from a season (defined by the id number entered). What i plan to do is use this to grab the information for a series and enter it into a database that can be accessed to use that information to tag MP4 files. Like [link](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=series&id=80270&lid=7)